# I want to know cache line size and what size is patched when write into array?

Tags: c

I want to implement an optimized queue between threads. To increase performance, I want to use pipeline techniques by splitting queue size.

I have a large queue for communication between two threads, one called producer, and another called consumer. By splitting queue size, if the producer writes in one part of the queue, the consumer can read the part that was written by producer. And when the consumer is reading a part of queue, the producer can write in the other part.

But I think when cache read array (because queue is made by array), the size doesn't same cache line size..

So I want to know what the size when cache bring array to write or read data.

Comment: That's architecture dependent. On Intel cache line is 64 bytes.

Comment: Could you clarify your last two sentences a bit? I tried making the whole text more understandable (English-wise), but I can't understand what the last two sentences mean

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Linux, this information is sometimes listed in `/proc/cpuinfo` as `cache_alignment`.

You could also find this information indirectly by stepping through an array, adjusting your stride, and timing the loop. When accesses aren't block aligned you'll see the performance drop, so you can get a pretty good idea of what your block size is. Here's a quick and dirty version to basically do this, I think it'll give you a good idea:

```
int main () {
    int i, STEP_SIZE = 8;
    int * a;
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double el;

    a = (int*)malloc(1024*1024*64*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < 1024*1024*64; i++)
        a[i] = 0;

    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 1024*1024*64; i += STEP_SIZE)
        a[i] += 10;

    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    el = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
    el += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;
    printf("%d %3.2f\n", STEP_SIZE, el);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically you would want to vary `STEP_SIZE`